# Creating personalized URLs (PURLs) in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I need to create a site that will allow for a unique user-identifying number to go in be appended to the URL.

So for instance

test.com/12345/about/

will load the page with slug 'about' (not redirect to it).

I have tried the following:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^([0-9]+)/', '/$matches[1]', 'bottom');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

But it does not work, any prefix to the URL redirects the page with or without the block of code above.

So in my tests

test.com/23423423/about will re-direct to test.com/about which is not what I want.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?  If so, could anyone offer advice as to how I would best go about implementing it?